# How to delete multiple plot axes made with subplot on scilab

Tags: graphics, subplot, figure, scilab

how are you. I've all day trying to do the following: I'm designing a PID controller and depending on how much data I want to analize then I show only one plot or four plots in the same figure (this last multiple plot is made with subplot).

All the calculation and plots are made in one function with options in function dependind on what I want to see, I have several buttons and text inputs in the application that I'm coding and right know the PID design and the simple or multiple plots are working; my current program is that the axes handle is being assigned to local variables inside the function and of course this variables are distroyed when the program exits the function.

A more detailed explanation of the problem is the following: if I select multiple plot and then I want one plot then I don't know how to delete the four axes to clean the figure without closing it, so when I want to activate the simple plot then the program only erases one of the four plots and prints the simple plot over the remaining three while the remaining three subplots remains visible. Following is the piece of code that is giving me problems:

```
grafico=sistem_graf;
disp(grafico);
if(isdef('aa')==%T);
    scf(aa);
    delete(get("current_axes"));
    disp("aa");
end
if(isdef('bb')==%T);
    scf(bb);
    delete(get("current_axes"));
    disp("bb");
end
if(isdef('cc')==%T);
    scf(cc);
    delete(get("current_axes"));
    disp("cc");
end
if(isdef('dd')==%T);
    scf(dd);
    delete(get("current_axes"));
    disp("dd");
end

select ventana
case 0
    tipoG=0;
    plot2d(T,graffta);
    xtitle('Ω(S)/R(S): Respuesta al escalón (Sistema original)','t [s]','Vel [rpm]'); 
    legend(['Original';'C/control P';'C/Control PI';'C/Control PID']);
    aa=get("current_axes");
    aa.axes_bounds = [1/3 0 2/3 1];
case 1
    tipoG=1;        
//        delete(get("current_axes"));        
    plot(T,[graffta;sist_P_ZN;sist_PI_ZN;sist_PID_ZN]);
    xtitle('Ω(S)/R(S): Respuesta al escalón','t [s]','Vel [rpm]'); 
    legend(['Original';'C/control P';'C/Control PI';'C/Control PID']);
    aa=get("current_axes");
    aa.axes_bounds=[1/3 0 2/3 1];
case 2
    tipoG=2;        
    //delete(get("current_axes"));  
    subplot(421);
    plot(T,[graffta;sist_P_ZN;sist_PI_ZN;sist_PID_ZN]);
    xtitle('Ω(S)/R(S): Respuesta al escalón','t [s]','Vel [rpm]'); 
    legend(['Original';'C/control P';'C/Control PI';'C/Control PID']);
    aa=get("current_axes");
    aa.axes_bounds=[1/3,0,1/3,1/2]
    subplot(422);
    plot2d(T,(kt*kp/(j*la))*(1/(afta*bfta))*(1+(1/(afta-bfta))*(bfta*exp(-afta*T)-afta*exp(-bfta*T))));
    xtitle('Ω(t)','t [s]','Vel [rpm]');
    bb=get("current_axes");
    bb.axes_bounds=[2/3,0,1/3,1/2];
    subplot(423);
    plot2d(T,(kt/(j*la))*(1/(afta*bfta))*((1/(afta-bfta))*(bfta*afta*exp(-bfta*T)-afta*bfta*exp(-afta*T))));
    xtitle('Variación de velocidad angular dΩ/dt','t [s]','Ac. [rpm/s^2]');
    cc=get("current_axes");
    cc.axes_bounds=[1/3,1/2,1/3,1/2];
    subplot(424);
    plot(T,[sist_P_ZN;sist_PI_ZN;sist_PID_ZN]);
    xtitle('Controladores','t [s]','Vel [rpm]');
    legend(['C/control P';'C/Control PI';'C/Control PID']);
    dd=get("current_axes");
    dd.axes_bounds=[2/3,1/2,1/3,1/2];
end
```

the four if(isdef("variable_name")) never doesn't works because when the program enters the functions those variables doesn't exists yet, those are created after the plots with subplot.

If the graphics properties are displayed from the Edit menú of the figure then all the children axes are shown but if I try to get the axes with for example

```
a=get(sistem_graf.Axes(1))
```

then a console display is shown saying that the property "Axes" doesn't exist so I don't know how to solve the problem.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Update 03/06/2021:

I found a way to have the behavior I need an is working at 90%, it only fails when I go from detailed plot to simple plot (is erasing one graphic) but backwards it works fine, I changed all the code before "Select ventana" to the following

```
if(imps(1) ~= -1)
    if(size(imps) == 1)
        sca(imps(1));
        disp(imps(1));
        delete(get("current_axes"));
    elseif(size(imps) > 1)
        sca(imps(1));
        delete(get("current_axes"));
        sca(imps(2));
        delete(get("current_axes"));
        sca(imps(3));
        delete(get("current_axes"));
        sca(imps(4));
        delete(get("current_axes"));
    end
end
```

and filled an array whose content is all the axes ploted last time that the function was called, that array is returned from the function to a global variable and finally that global variable is feed to the function in the next call and assigned to the local variable "imps".

I think is some kind of crazy but apparently scilab doesn't have incorpotated the static variable aproach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your problem, the small example below should help you:

```
function fun(nb)
    ch = gcf().Children;
    delete(ch(ch.type=="Axes"))
    t = linspace(0,1,100);
    if nb==1
        plot(t,t)
    else
        for i=1:nb
            subplot(2,2,i)
            plot(t,t.^i)
        end
    end
endfunction
clf
uicontrol("style","pushbutton","units","normalized","Position",[0.1 0.1 0.4 0.1],"string","one plot","callback","fun(1)");
uicontrol("style","pushbutton","units","normalized","Position",[0.5 0.1 0.4 0.1],"string","four plots","callback","fun(4)");
```

I think that the mechanism you were missing is the following:

```
ch = gcf().Children;
delete(ch(ch.type=="Axes"))
```

i.e. something that allows to delete the plot axes and keep the uicontrols alive. The above construct uses logical indexing. Here `ch.type=="Axes"` is a vector of boolean values with components `i` egal to true when the `type` field of corresponding component `ch(i)` is `Axes`. Then, `ch(ch.type=="Axes")` is the subset of components of `ch` such that the boolean index has value true. Hence, at last, the subset of components of `ch` which are of `Axes` type.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane Mottelet but, will this kind of assign survive the exit from the function?, I ask this because after a simple plot or a detailed plot (four subplots) the program exits the function and it calls the function again only when I press the button for plotting the system

Comment: Mottelet I've just tried your suggestion but apparently I corfirmed my last comment. I think the tags doesn't survive the exit from the function where are created

Comment: I will try to explain better the current problem, I followed your answer and now the axes have a tag, the function ends and main program takes control. Then from main program I call the function again but when I try to find the tags created before inside the function, those tags aren't found and the plots still appears in the figure

Comment: There is new information on some advances to erase the plots, please reade from the line that says "Update 03/06/2021"

Comment: Just to be sure: you can't just use `clf`to clear the figure because you have plots and uicontrols, that's it ? I mean, depending on the choices made in the uicontrols, you have a different number of plots in the figure (hence have to erase the previous plots each time the choices are different) ?

Comment: Thanks again Stephane, exactly those two lines of code saved about 15 lines of code but there is something that I don't fully understand in the line "delete(ch(ch.type=="Axes"))", I know that sentence erases only the axes but I don't fully comprehend the code, to be more precise I don't understand why -ch.type=="Axes"- ins enclosed in parenthesis

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain the logical indexing feature of Scilab.

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, you've been very helpful but I have another question: that way of write the sentence by applying "ch(ch.type=="Axes")" is a characteristic of scilab or is a standard way of write sentences in OOP?, Is some sord of confusing to me the fact of see the result of a logical operation as an argument for the "ch" variable since I come from C and I  coded not too much in OOP, that's what made me ask you before

Comment: That's a common feature of dynamically typed languages like Matlab, Octave, Scilab, Julia. See e.g. https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/